# A function where an infinitesimal difference in intial conditions grows into a finitesimal difference in final conditions, within finite time?

Tags: chaos-theory, lyapunov-functions

The typical functions I see with finite Lyapunov times are merely exponential; they only generate (e times larger) infinitesimal differences in final conditions from infinitesimal differences in initial conditions. This means that, in principle, it's possible to keep increasing the precision of initial conditions to keep extending the predictability of the modeled system out forever. Not in practice, but in principle.

I'm interested in looking at some functions where that is no longer possible, even in principle.

Answer (score 0):

For a continuous phase-space flow $Φ$, infinitesimal changes to a state $x$ only beget infinitesimal changes to the evolved state $Φᵗ(x)$. That’s already the definition of *continuity.* So, what you want is equivalent to discontinuities in the phase-space flow.

For a dynamical system, your flow can at best be discontinuous at discrete points. For such a system, you can have what you want at the discontinuities. A very simple example is the [bit-shift map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation), which is discontinuous at $\tfrac{1}{2}$: The flow maps $\tfrac{1}{2}$ to $1$ and $\tfrac{1}{2}+ε$ to $2ε$.

What you cannot have is that the flow is discontinuous everywhere, because then nobody (I am aware of) would call the result a dynamical system – or flow for that matter.

Comment: I was expecting some hyperbolic functions, since they achieve infinite growth within finite intervals. Why are all chaotic functions merely exponential and not hyperbolic? But thanks you anyway. Are there bit-shift map type behavior found in nature?

Comment: @Jurhas: Chaos is bounded by definition and thus cannot have infinite values or distances between trajectories. Even if we ignore this, a hyperbolic trajectory would violate continuity at its singularity – which is okay, but you cannot have that everywhere. — As to why divergences of trajectories are infinite, please see [this answer of mine). — Yes, you can find such behaviour in reality, e.g., when a ball rolling down an inclined plane almost hits a wire perpendicular to that plane: It can either pass the wire on the left or right side.